# Add formatting to Excel formula of nested functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested-function

I have the following formula: `=ROUND(CONVERT(D157,"mi","km"),0)&"kms"`

When the resulting number displays, it does so without "thousands" commas: ie - `3015kms`.

I'm sure I need to use some sort of `TEXT` function with `#`s, `0`s and commas, but can't work out how to nest them successfully.

Comment: By concatenating the unit with `&` you are ensuring your cell is treated as a string, not a number, so the number formatting won't apply.

Comment: You might be able to do a custom format for the cells and not put the concatenation in your cell formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=TEXT(ROUND(CONVERT(D157,"mi","km"),0),"#,###")&"kms"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @pnuts; however, it brings back only "kms" (without the quote marks) and no preceding number...?

Comment: My fault @pnuts, it works perfectly, thank you! (I had since moved the information into a different cell, so when I copied and pasted yours in, it was of course the wrong cell!)